# Как замедлить цикл в C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Timer не подойдет. Я пробовал Thread.Sleep(1000), но интерфейс не отображается.

Comment: Вынесите выполнение процедуры в отдельный поток и уже этот поток замедляйте через `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qWait

Comment: @S.Nick C# же..